# JavaScript object array Group By and Get values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, lodash

I want to do a `groupBy` for the below object array on `deptId` and I should be able to display the data on page using AngularJS as below

I have an object like this:

```
var arr = [
     {deptId: '12345',deptName: 'Marketing', divId: '1231',divName: 'Lead'},
     {deptId: '12345',deptName: 'Marketing', divId: '8796',divName: 'Assistants'},
     {deptId: '32145',deptName: 'Sales', divId: '1231',divName: 'Lead'},
     {deptId: '32145',deptName: 'Sales', divId: '8796',divName: 'Assistants'},
     {deptId: '32145',deptName: 'Sales', divId: '8221',divName: 'Associates'}
]
```

Display on ui as below

```
 Marketing
 <ul>
   <li>Lead 
   <li>Assistants
 </ul>
 Sales
 <ul>
   <li>Lead
   <li> Assistants
   <li> Associates
 </ul>
```

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: I tried doing this 

 var result = _.chain(vm.ohcUser.departments).groupBy("deptId").pairs()
                .map(function (currentItem) {
                    return _.object(_.zip(["deptId", "depts"], currentItem));
                }).value();

Comment: your going way to far it's actually simplier than that

Comment: please search for this first before asking questions....there are lots of `angular groupBy` examples all over the web as well as questions on this site  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=angular+groupBy

Comment: <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="(key, depts) in arr | groupBy:'deptId'">
                {{key}}
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="dept in depts">
                        {{dept.divName}}
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
I also tried this this just gives me deptId and grouped data as list items as below. 12345
Lead
Assistants
32145
Lead
Assistants
Associates

but in my case deptName is not unique and deptId is unique but I should display deptName for each department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lodash allow you to do that pretty easily:

```
var sortedDept = _.groupBy(arr, function(ite){return ite.deptName});
```

Now you can access by  sortedDept.Marketing --> give you an array with only marketing related object.

And just display those values.

Comment: The problem here is Dept name is not unique and it can be duplicate and deptId is unique

Comment: don't get your point. With this solution you will get object grouped on array by their deptName. Test and console log the output, you will see